# comparing the array element with an integer

Tags: c#

I have an list and I want to compare a dynamic integer with the elements of the array. How should I do that ??

I have a list as findcolnumber whose elements are: 1,8,9,10,11 and they are generated dynamically.
I generate one another integer rowcount. If the value of rowcount is equalto any of those single value 1,8,9,10,11, then only it should go in the for loop.

The list findcolnumber is generated dynamically. Also findcolnumber[what should i keep inside this bracket].

```
if(findcolnumber[] == rowcount) {
    proceed
}
```

Comment: I think that you must use findcolnumber.Count

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question. Do you want to know how to check if an integer exists in an array of integers?

Comment: It is a list. and yes i want to compare the list with an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

you will have to include this namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then you can do this:

```
if(findcolnumber.Contains(rowcount))
{
    //your logic
}
```

where rowcount is some integer i.e.

```
int rowcount = getDynamicIntegar();
```

and findcolnumber is:

```
int[] findcolnumber = {1,8,9,10,11};
```

linq `.Contains` returns boolean value, if your dynamic integer will exist in the integral array, .Contains will return `true` otherwise `false`

`.Contains` `extension`, if you bother to see, will be available for your `List<int>` as well.

same way you can compare any `List` or `Collection` implementing `IEnumerable` interface

you can only pass the collection's base datatype in `.Contains`

i.e. if findcolnumber is `List<int>` then

you can `findcolnumber.Contains(integralValueOrVariable)`

if findcolnumber is `List<string>` then

you can `findcolnumber.Contains(stringValueOrVariable)`

Comment: `you will have to include this namespace`. No you have not to.

Comment: It is a list. How should i proceed then ?
findcolumn is a list.

Comment: I will still not use extension methods for simpler lists and arrays.

Comment: @user2163048 both my method and Manish's method work on Lists, infact any datastructure(including a simple array) that implements the IEnumerable<T> interface.

Comment: AgentFire, you have to include that namespace, i am pretty sure, and Ankiet, iterating through a loop is a bit longer code thn directly doing .Contains

Comment: .Contains also iterates through the loop, finding it with linear search algorithm, its just that .Contains is defined as a yielding value, lazily evaluating the IEnumerable object

Comment: @ManishMishra getting the eeror..it contains invalid argument..when i use
if(findcolnumber.Contains(rowcount))

Comment: what is your findcolnumber, is it not a List<int>? if yes, then make sure rowcount variable is an int

Comment: wow, then do this, findcolnumber.Contains(rowCount.ToString())

Comment: got it..thanx bro... help appreciated